# Phonegap Build Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have in an app for Android/iOS with a plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" to login with Facebook. It's not working anymore so I thought I should have to change it for another one, anyway it won't compile anymore case Phonegape Build has got rid of their Repository. 
Problem is that any plugin I try that is in `https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/` ... Throw the same error message when trying to compile:

> Error - One of your plugins requires a parameter - You can fix this
>   here

I tried:

```
cordova-plugin-facebook
cordova-plugin-facebook4
xenious-cordova-plugin-facebook4
cordova-plugin-facebook-account-kit
etc ..
```

And I defined them in config.xml in all different ways possible:

```
<plugin name="plugin-name" source="npm" >
    <param name="APP_ID" value="123456" />
    <param name="APP_NAME " value="name" />
<plugin> 

<plugin name="plugin-name" source="npm" >
    <params>
        <param name="APP_ID" value="123456" />
        <param name="APP_NAME " value="name" />
    </params>
<plugin> 

<plugin name="plugin-name" source="npm" >
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="123456" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME " value="name" />
<plugin>
```

- APP_ID for some of the plugins is FACEBOOK_APP_ID and another one has one more value: AK_TOKEN. Just put examples of how I define them in config.xml

Funny is that if I don't put anything just the plugin without parameters, the message is different:

> Error - One of your plugins requires a parameter: APP_ID, APP_NAME,
>   AK_TOKEN - You can fix this here

I made a new "Hello world" app without any plugin but this one and it is the same. I'm running out of ideas. Do I have to define those parameters somewhere else? Didn't use to be that way with the previous plugin I had. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You must set the parameters as follows:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4">
    <params>
       <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
       <param name="APP_NAME" value="XXXXXXX" />
    </params>
 </plugin>
```

preference set in **config.xml**

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Anuj, it seems the problem I had was that I have to define spec="1.7.4" in the plugin. Also had to define the android-minSdkVersion to 15 as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally make it work.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" source="npm" spec="1.7.4">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="XXXXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

The difference was the spec"1.7.4" ...

After that, the build sent me a message that I had to define the android-minSdkVersion at the minimum necessary for the plugin, by default 14 if not stated. So placed this line also in config.xml

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
```